# Address Data and Coordinates in Germany

Tags: data-request, database, real-estate, address

I'm looking to purchase the a database containing all the address data in Germany including the coordinates of these properties.

Does anyone know where I can download such a database or a provider that could provide one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use OSM data: https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/

Regards,
Grzegorz

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the OSM data but I believe this data includes all buildings including farm houses, factories, ect. I am only looking for the residential data. Thanks for the suggestion as it is a great resource!

Comment: You can filter out certain building types. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:building